# Newly added data is not showing in gridview

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have four `DropDownList` which are bonded to the `GridView`.
Whenever I fill `DropDownList` the data is getting displayed in `GridView`.
Out of four `DropDownList`, I have attached two `TextBox` to two `DropDownList` to add new data through `TextBox` to `DropDownList`.
That data is getting stored in database but not getting displayed in `GridView`.

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int flag = 0;
   if (CheckBox1.Checked)
   {

       if (TextBox1.Text == "" && TextBox2.Text == "")
       {
           Label2.Text = "Enter Value !!";
           TextBox1.Focus();
           TextBox2.Focus();
           Label2.Visible = true;
           flag = 1;
       }
       else 
       {

       }

   }

   if (flag == 0 && CheckBox1.Checked == true)
   {
       String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr (CallType, SUBFormat,Disposition, SubDisposition) values (@CallType, @Format,@Disposition, @SubDisposition)", con);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", ddlCalltype.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", ddlFormat.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Disposition", TextBox1.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", TextBox2.Text);

       con.Open();
       int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();


       Label2.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
       Label2.Text = " Your data is been saved in the database";
       Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;

   }
   else { }  
}

 protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDispositionDetails();
        }



        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("ROMA_UserManagement", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CallType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlCalltype.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Format", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlFormat.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@disposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlDisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubDisposition", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlSubdisp.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(dt);

            }
            con.Close();
        }
        gvDetails.DataSource = dt;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
        gvDetails.Visible = true;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the Data to `GridView` after updating the database. 
Call the function after insert statement `Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)`

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   .......
   ........
   Label2.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
   Label2.Text = " Your data is been saved in the database";
   Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
   //add this line 
   Button2_Click1(sender, e);
 }
```

Comment: @user31121992 add the last line see the answer.

Comment: i am not getting please elaborate

Comment: you need to add the last line `Button2_Click1(sender, e);` in your code.

Comment: create a separate function for grid data bind and call it after inserting data into database.

Comment: can u give any example